# Are all Superior Highly Composite Numbers multiples of all smaller Superior Highly Composite Numbers?

Tags: factoring

Looking at the Wikipedia entry on the topic:

[Superior Highly Composite Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superior_highly_composite_number)

It is true of all numbers listed there. Does this commonality continue forever?

Put another way: Are all SHCNs factors of all larger SHCNs?